# MAUI Blazor - How to use static images

Tags: c#, maui-blazor

I'm testing the new .NET MAUI with Blazor, but I can't display images.

So I have 2 questions :

- Which folder should I use ? Resources or wwwroot ?
- How to display an image with an img tag :
  `<img src=" ?? Which path ??">`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've a folder in the wwwroot file, which is called Images.

[image]

The img tag is:

```
<img src="Images/YOURPICTURENAME.png" />
```

Comment: Omg I don't know what I've done. I thought it was the first things I tried...
But you're right, it works like that. Thanks

Comment: How to upload files to the wwwroot to use them as src?

Comment: Just create a folder in the wwwroot file and drag & drop your image in the folder.

Comment: Just so you know currenty importing static files from a razor class library doesnt seem to load them on android, at least for me :)