# Blazor Maui JS Isolation

Tags: c#, blazor, maui, maui-blazor

I am working on a Blazor Maui app and I cannot load my js files for my components. I keep getting the exception.

Exception:

```
Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: https://0.0.0.0/_content/MyAppName/js/MyFile.js
```

```
[Inject] IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }
private Task<IJSObjectReference> _module;
const string ImportPath = "./_content/MyAppName/js/MyFile.js";
private Task<IJSObjectReference> Module => _module ??= JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", ImportPath).AsTask();
```

When I invoke the below code I get the exception.

```
var module = await Module;
```

Comment: Can you put it in [local `wwwroot` folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69988086/199364)? Or access via [MauiAsset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70442740/199364)?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I used the wwwroot folder to place my JS files.

Comment: What is "the exception"? What does it say? I think you either need to have the javascript file inside of your wwwroot file or define it as MyPage.razor.js to match an existing razor page

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to access the wwwroot content from within the same application, the path should be like this `const string ImportPath = "./js/MyFile.js";`. You only use `./_content/<AppName>/` when accessing content from another Library.